# Flask rendering template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I try to insert data to my template render_template.

```
data = Bill.bill_data(self)
        return render_template('templates/bill.html', **data)
```

Bill template location in folder templates. But I've got this error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: templates/bill.html
```

My data looks like this:

```
data={
        "payer_currency": "5",
        "shop_amount": "5",
        "shop_currency": "5",
        "shop_id": "5",
        "shop_order_id": "12",
        "sign": ""
        }
```

Comment: Probably '/templates/bill.html' will work?

Comment: you don't have to add `templates/` in path - as default it search in folder `templates`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add `templates/` in path. As default `render_template` searchs template in folder `templates`

```
return render_template('bill.html', **data)
```